# GitLab stops rendering in-text LaTeX for markdown files after 50 occurrences

Tags: gitlab, markdown, katex

I have been using GitLab's LaTeX rendering feature in Markdown, and enjoy it tremendously. That being said, I have found that there is an upper limit to the number of in-text latex references.

After exactly 50 occurrences on one page, rendering will stop, with formatting changing from this (desired behavior)

> ... where <ASSUME CORRECT LATEX HERE> is maximized ...

to this

> ... where $`\Delta \rho^\prime`$ is maximized ...

(incorrect behavior). This is reproducible, with a minimal example [**uploaded to my gitlab here**](https://gitlab.cern.ch/llepotti/latex_stackoverflow/-/blob/master/README.md).

I have searched for any relevant information and have been unable to find any information on this limit, though I have found [**this gitlab issue**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/243533) which seems to be related, but does not solve the problem.

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable/bypass this limit, or else submit a ticket to the GitLab developers?

Thanks either way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be related to [issue 333514](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/333514)

> Current limitations on Math rendering is 1000 total characters per page OR 2000ms of runtime, whichever happens first, helps in preventing a DoS attack on all pages where we can render GFM.
>
> This is non-ideal for pages like Wikis where
>
> - There is no user-generated content.
> - The math diagrams can quickly rack up 2000ms of runtime or 1000 chars.

A possible workaround can be found in [`j7168908jx/gitlab` merge_requests 1](https://gitlab.com/j7168908jx/gitlab/-/merge_requests/1)

[image: https://gitlab.com/j7168908jx/gitlab/uploads/d888dec18b9c468e1c475b71f9b6fa26/image.png]

Comment: https://github.com/j7168908jx/commonmarker is also of interest.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. That looks like it would fix the problem. I suppose then I just need to wait until the system admins for my gitlab (CERN) apply this fix?

Comment: @LucLePottier yes, that would be the idea.